# Creation on Jenkins Job using curl Jenkinsfile

Tags: curl, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to use curl to create a Jenkins job using Jenkinsfile inside Gitlab?

Currently i am using

> curl -s -XPOST 'http://JENKINS_URL/createItem?name=New_Job' -u username:API_Token --data-binary @mypipeline.xml -H "Content-Type:text/xml"
>   Here mypipeline.xml contain configuration of pipeline project